# Why img and address elements do not aligh vertically in a most trivial page?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page with two elements - address and img. I have changed the display of the address element to inline and expected that the two elements will align vertically, both being inline elements.

This is not true, please observe - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/Q8ygG/19/

What is wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

I want the address and the logo to be horizontally aligned i.e. be on the same horizontal level:

```
+-------+  +----+
|ADDRESS|  |LOGO|
+-------+  +----+
```

**EDIT2**

I think I have confused everyone. I want the elements to be on the same line, which probably means vertical alignment and not horizontal. I have fixed the wording of the question. Sorry.

**EDIT3**

An important addition. When the window is resized, I would like the address and the logo to retain their relative positions rather than the logo float below the address. If needed, scroll bars should appear.

Comment: I see on the jsFiddle that the address element and img are left aligned... Isn't it what you expected?

Comment: I want them to be on the same level

Comment: Again, I don't get it... maybe you should explain better what are you visually expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always include this in my stylesheet:

```
img{border:0;vertical-align:bottom}
```

This ensures proper alignment in most cases. The only time an issue may arise is when the image is shorter than the line-height.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate your point using my example?

Comment: Thanks, however, resizing the window brings the logo beneath the address instead of showing the scroll bar. This is the same issue as with the response of PeterVR. He suggests a way to solve it, but I think it is problematic -  please refer to his reply and the accompanying comments.

Comment: You could try adding `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:auto`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer twice. Could you explain the magic?

Comment: `display:inline-block` basically makes it so that your elements are treated like individual characters. `white-space: nowrap` prevents those characters from going onto separate lines, and the `overflow: auto` adds a scrollbar when needed.

Answer (score 2):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8ygG/4/ I guess yhis is what you are after?...

I am not a big fan of using inline or inline-block. They will cause you a huge pain when you want to get them to work in older versions of IE. I prefer working with floats, they are much more predictable and work cross browser.

**edit:**

just saw your edit. You would affcourse have to change the order of img and address in my fiddle to gte what you are after, but that is probably obvious...

Comment: +1 for making it responsive even if I don't know if it's wanted.

Comment: It is almost. The only problem is that when I resize the window, the image floats below the address, instead of showing a scroll bar.

Comment: You should be able to prevent that by setting a min-width on the container.

Comment: But then I have to know it. For the image is easy. But what about the address? Its width depends on the font used to display the address, doesn't it? If I later change the font, then I will have to change the min-width value, no?

Comment: that is true indeed. You could calculate in some margin though, so the text has room to grow. Or you could just set it way up, but then you'll get the scrollbars way to early...

Answer (score 0):

Change the display for both elements to `inline-block`:

```
#own_address {
    outline: green solid 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
    outline: green solid 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry to have confused you. I guess I need vertical alignment.